# BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:721307821>, App: com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication

I am having issue to Display the map on the Application.Its Showing error of the  BAD_AUTHENTICATION.I am quite Surprised that it is Working properly yesterday but now the Log is Showing BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="********" />
```

**Log**

```
10-04 07:50:21.901 2074-3612/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:721307821>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/emeraldsea.mobileapps.doritos.cookie
                                                                       edx: Long live credential not available.
                                                                           at edy.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:10)
                                                                           at edy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:50)
                                                                           at ecl.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:50)
                                                                           at flk.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:8)
                                                                           at flk.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:4)
                                                                           at fkj.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:2)
                                                                           at fkh.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:17)
                                                                           at fkh.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:6)
                                                                           at bsr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:203)
                                                                           at bsr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:61)
                                                                           at bsr.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:6)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                           at buy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:3)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

> How can this issue be solved???